# New custom PC refuses to boot (black screen) after I attach a (verified working) SATA drive

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, sata

Here are the steps I'm able to reproduce every time (6 tries so far)

1. Install Windows from USB drive onto M.2 drive in m2_1 port
2. Shut down computer and attach one of my 6 SATA drives (that's verified to work in my old computer) to a random SATA port
3. Black screen on boot.
4. Shut down, disconnect SATA drive.
5. Black screen on boot.
6. Clear CMOS
7. Black Screen on boot.
8. Start over with step 1 and a different SATA drive and port

I have NO idea why clearing the CMOS isn't fixing things; it's like something on the M.2 drive is being corrupted when I plug in a SATA drive.

Things work fine when it's just two M.2 drives in m2_1 and m2_3, but I have six legacy drives from an older system to bring over.

I've also flashed the BIOS to current, per a suggestion on a different forum.

Specs:

- [Intel Core i5-12600K - Core i5 12th Gen Alder Lake 10-Core (6P+4E) 3.7 GHz LGA 1700 125W Intel UHD Graphics 770 Desktop](https://www.newegg.com/intel-core-i5-12600k-core-i5-12th-gen/p/N82E16819118347)
- [ASRock Z690 Steel Legend LGA 1700 Intel Z690 SATA 6Gb/s DDR4 ATX Intel Motherboard](https://www.newegg.com/p/N82E16813162027)
- [SAMSUNG 980 PRO M.2 2280 500GB PCI-Express Gen 4.0 x4, NVMe 1.3c Samsung V-NAND Internal Solid State Drive (SSD)](https://www.newegg.com/samsung-500gb-980-pro/p/N82E16820147789?Item=N82E16820147789)
- 2x (4 cards) [CORSAIR Vengeance RGB Pro 32GB (2 x 16GB) 288-Pin DDR4 SDRAM DDR4 3200 (PC4 25600) Intel XMP 2.0 Desktop Memory](https://www.newegg.com/corsair-32gb-288-pin-ddr4-sdram/p/N82E16820236570)

Edit: removing 2 RAM sticks does nothing. Disabling the boot logo screen just results in a black screen; no POST messages beyond the prompt to press keys to enter UEFI and boot menu, etc.

Edit2: POST is reporting A0 (which google says means control is handed over from MoBo to the boot drive). Is it possible that, when detecting the new SATA drive, the MoBo is corrupting the M.2 installation?

Edit: Installing windows with all drives attached "worked" until I unplugged one of them. However, Windows did a massive update for me overnight (one that wasn't listed in the available updates when searching) and now everything works fine.

Comment: The problem might be that there are UEFI boot or active MBR partitions on the drives you’re plugging in. Did any of the drives contain a working operating system? You’re not clear if the screen is just blank. Or if it goes blank after POSTing. Install your OS, plug in all your drives, and boot your windows installation media and use bcdedit to fix up the boot entries. It could mean setting the active boot partition, or cleaning up old ones, etc. essentially remove any .efi files from the old disks and/or remove the active bit from any MBR partitions and fix up the UEFI boot entries.

Comment: @Appleoddity I don't think that's it. None of the currently attached drives have ever had an OS installed (and if they had, I expect they'd show up in the boot menu; only the m2_1 C drive does). After much tinkering, I discovered that if I install Windows with any drives attached, it works just fine with all those drives, but the moment I detach one, it soft-bricks again. A single time, I got it to boot to windows by entering UEFI and then exiting with the desired drive selected, but that wasn't repeatable.

Comment: "You’re not clear if the screen is just blank. Or if it goes blank after POSTing." - It goes blank after POST. I'll try the bcedit thing, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Huge windows update seems to have solved things.

Comment: Telling us which update could make this a better answer and more helpful to others who may have the same issue.

Comment: So you "black screen" initially meant that Windows was booting, but got stuck? Maybe disabling "fast boot" in BIOS (or "display diagnostic messages") might help, too. I had a similar problem occasionally when Windows was shutdown for "fast boot". What helped was to disconnect some USB pen drive until Windows had booted.